# How to make an uptime command in nodejs tmijs chat bot

Tags: node.js, chatbot, twitch

How would you make an uptime command with tmi.js, I thought it would be as simple as;

```
client.on("chat", function(channel, user, message, self, uptime){ 
client.say("CHANNEL", "Channel has been live for " + uptime
})
```

How would you go about making this command, the example I gave does not work and I would request you to let me know.

Comment: I think I missunderstood your question.  What uptime are you asking for?  The **channel** uptime or the **node.js process** uptime?

Comment: I am looking for the channel uptime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like channel metadata is available over the [Twitch WebSocket API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/pubsub/).  If you want to get that information, you'll need to go through the "New Twitch API" and use the [`/streams`](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-streams) endpoint.

You will also need to have a `Client-ID` to make requests to this endpoint.  You can get one by following the instructions here: [Apps & Authentication Guide](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/#registration).

Once you have a `Client-ID`, you can make a request.  I'm using the `node-fetch` module to make requests easier.  This example will get the 2 most active streams.  You can adjust the query string parameters to get the appropriate stream.

```
const querystring = require("querystring"),
    fetch = require("node-fetch");

const CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
const STREAMS_URL = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams";

const qs = querystring.stringify({
    first: 2
});

const qUrl = `${STREAMS_URL}?${qs}`;

const fetchArgs = {
    headers: {
        "Client-ID": CLIENT_ID
    }
};

fetch(qUrl, fetchArgs)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

This would print out something like the following:

```
{
    data: [{
            id: '28378863024',
            user_id: '19571641',
            game_id: '33214',
            community_ids: [],
            type: 'live',
            title: 'Morning Stream! | @Ninja on Twitter and Insta ;)',
            viewer_count: 107350,
            started_at: '2018-04-18T14:58:45Z',
            language: 'en',
            thumbnail_url: 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_ninja-{width}x{height}.jpg'
        },
        {
            id: '28379115264',
            user_id: '22859264',
            game_id: '32399',
            community_ids: [Array],
            type: 'live',
            title: 'LIVE: Astralis vs. Space Soldiers - BO1 - CORSAIR DreamHack Masters Marseille 2018 - Day 1',
            viewer_count: 54354,
            started_at: '2018-04-18T15:28:44Z',
            language: 'nl',
            thumbnail_url: 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_dreamhackcs-{width}x{height}.jpg'
        }]
}
```

The `started_at` property is the timestamp of when the stream began.  Bear in mind that this API is rate limited so you should probably cache the `started_at` so you don't immediately run out of requests.